# how to reset datetimefield in django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I doubt in the DateTime field, my 'course' model has a field called "publish_date" and if the course is published then "course.publish_date = datetime.datetime.now ()".
Also, there is a chance that the published course will not be published, so I should be able to change it to publish_date = null, But it makes mistakes, give me a solution to fix it.

views.py

```
class PublishCourseViewSet(ResponseViewMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    def put(self, request, course_id=None, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            course = get_object_or_404(Course, pk=course_id)
            course_status = course.review_status
            if course_status == 'review_passed':
                course.review_status = 'published'
                course.publish_date = datetime.datetime.now()
                course.save(update_fields=["review_status", "publish_date"])
                serializer = CourseListSerializer(course)
                return self.jp_response(s_code='HTTP_200_OK', data=serializer.data)
            else:
                return self.jp_error_response('HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST', {"detail": "course not yet ready for publishing"})
        except Exception as e:
            return self.jp_error_response('HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR', 'EXCEPTION', [str(e), ])


class UnPublishCourseViewSet(ResponseViewMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    def put(self, request, course_id=None, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            course = get_object_or_404(Course, pk=course_id)
            course_status = course.review_status
            if course_status == 'published':
                course.review_status = 'review_passed'
                course.publish_date = null
                course.save(update_fields=["review_status", "publish_date"])
                serializer = CourseListSerializer(course)
                return self.jp_response(s_code='HTTP_200_OK', data=serializer.data)
            else:
                return self.jp_error_response('HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST', {"detail": "course not yet ready for publishing"})
        except Exception as e:
            return self.jp_error_response('HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR', 'EXCEPTION', [str(e), ])
```

Comment: Use `None` in Python not `null`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not work with `null`, you should work with `None`, `None` is the equivalent of `NULL` at the Django/Python layer:

```
course.publish_date = None
```

I would advise *not* to use a blanket try-except clause. Such mechanism catches all exceptions, but not only the ones where the data is invalid, but also the ones where the source code doesn't make sense (which was the case here).